# Properties of Matrices obtained from Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

Let $I=\delta_{ij}$ be the identity matrix of order $n$ and $J_{k\ell}=I(k\leftrightarrow \ell)$ i.e. $J_{k\ell}$ formed by interchanging the $\ell$
th and $k$
th
columns of the identity matrix.

> Is there any simple and tricky way to calculate the following actions (or should I do it manually?)
>
> 1. $A\times J_{k\ell}$ for $A\in \mathbf{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$.
> 2. $ J_{k\ell}\times A$.
> 3. $ J_{st}\times J_{k\ell}\times A$.

and please tell me any other property if you know.

Comment: Are you familiar with elementary row and column operations?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: Is the "$\times$" in $A \times J_{k\ell}$ supposed to denote the usual matrix-multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $A \times B$ simply denotes the usual product $AB$ of two matrices.

Here's an approach that you might like.  Note that the $i,j$ entry of $A$ is given by $e_i^TAe_j$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th column of the identity matrix (AKA the $i$th standard basis vector) and $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$. Note also that $J_{k\ell}^T = J_{k\ell}$, and that
$$
J_{k\ell}e_i = \begin{cases}
e_k & i=\ell\\
e_\ell & i = k\\
e_i  & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
With that, we find, for instance, that 
$$
[J_{k\ell}A]_{ij} = e_i^TJ_{k\ell}Ae_j
= (J_{k\ell} e_i)^TAe_j
= \begin{cases}
e_k^TAe_j & i=\ell\\
e_\ell^TAe_j & i = k\\
e_iAe_j  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
= \begin{cases}
A_{kj} & i=\ell\\
A_{\ell j} & i = k\\
A_{ij}  & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
In other words, we find that $J_{k\ell}A$ has the same entries as $A$ except the $\ell$th and $k$th rows have been exchanged.  So, the action $A \mapsto J_{k\ell}A$ is the exchange (AKA transposition) of these two rows.

---

Note that we can find the product of such "$J$ matrices" (for instance, $J_{st}J_{k\ell}$) by noting that $J_{k\ell}$ is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) and that a product of permutation matrices corresponds to a composition of the associated permutations.

Comment: Is $J_{k\ell}=J_{\ell k}$ correct?

Comment: @C.F.G yes.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: So changing rows is same as columns? and no matter in which side (right or left) acting on matrices.

Comment: I want to interchange $a_{ii}$ and $a_{jj}$. How can I do that using $J_{k\ell}$s.?

Comment: @C.F.G multiplying from the left exchanges rows and multiplying from the right exchanges columns.  If you want to exchange $a_{kk},a_{\ell \ell}$, you could use the map $A \mapsto J_{k\ell} A J_{k \ell}$.  Keep in mind that other entries of $A$ will also be moved around.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by $\times $ you denote the usual matrix product. Then the result of $A \times J_{kl}$ is the matrix $A$ where the $k$-th and $l$-th column are interchangedor in your notation $A \times J_{kl} = A(k\leftrightarrow l)$. Analogously $ J_{kl} \times A$ is the matrix $A$ where line $k$ and $l$ are interchanged. I will demonstrate the former: Let $B_i$ denote the $i$-th column of $B = A \times J_{kl}$. Then $$B_i = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m=1}^n A^{1,m} J_{kl}^{m,i} \\ \vdots \\\sum_{m=1}^n A^{n,m} J_{kl}^{m,i}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{cases}\begin{pmatrix} A^{1,l} & \dots & A^{n,l}\end{pmatrix}^T& \text {for } i = k. \\ \begin{pmatrix} A^{1,k} & \dots & A^{n,k}\end{pmatrix}^T& \text {for } i = l. \\ \begin{pmatrix} A^{1,i} & \dots & A^{n,i}\end{pmatrix}^T& \text {else}.\end{cases}$$