# How to verify this simple matrix equation in $sl(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X$ be in the center of $sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ and let $E_{jk}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in the $jk$ position and $0$'s elsewhere. Next let $H_{jk} = E_{jj} - E_{kk}$. I am told that
$$0 = [H_{jk},X] = 2X_{jk}E_{jk} - 2X_{kj}E_{kj}$$
Where we use the lie bracket $[A,B] = AB - BA$. The first equality is because $X$ is in the center, but I can't seem to justify the second equality. I would think $X_{jk}$ to be the $jk$ element of $X$, but it could also be some form of matrix multiplication. The author doesn't say. When I work out simple examples I get very different things on either side. I think that $E_{jk}X$ will give me a matrix whose $k^{th}$ row is the $j^{th}$ row of $X$ and something similar with columns on the right, but that doesn't seem to do it. This is from Brian Hall's Lie Groups book, pg $171$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3581920/272127) may help you?

Comment: @C.F.G Yes that post is clear and I understand it, but I don't see how to apply it here.

Comment: Use the formula for $[E_{ij},E_{kl}]$, given in books on Lie algebras, e.g., in Humphrey's book. Note that $X$ is the linear combination of all $E_{ij}$ with coefficients $X_{ij}$.

Comment: (if I am not mistaken!) $A\times E_{st}$ gives a matrix with $s$-th row filled with $t$-th column of $A$ and $E_{st}\times A$ gives a matrix with $s$-th column filled with $t$-th row of $A$ and zero in other places. I think this may be helpful to deduce $X$ is diagonal but this is not same as Hall's Book!